# ruby database query date formats

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

OK my app has two date select fields. However this passes back to the database date(3i) (2i) (1i) for Month/day/year. Sqlite doesn't like it. I have read some statements about date:civil but I'm a bit lost. How do I get the date to be entered into the database from both date selects.

I'm new to all this.

```
date(3i):string date(2i):string date(1i):string 

<%= f.label :date, 'Date of Request:', :class=>'label'%>  <%= f. date_select :date,     options= { order: [:day, :month, :year ]}
```

and this is what is in the error log...

```
=>" SUBMIT REQUEST"}
Unpermitted parameters: date(3i), date(2i), date(1i),
```

Comment: Can you please paste the stack trace or some code?
This will greatly help to solve the issue

Comment: I have edited the above. However when it tries to add the items to the DB it doesn't like the brackets. This looks like a normal known issue hence the date:civil but not sure how to implement it.

Comment: the above is not valid ruby, what is the date field called??, you can use [`date_select`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/DateHelper.html#method-i-date_select) in your view, if the field is a `date` field already

Comment: ok I am using date_select form helper.. that works all good. However when the user inputs the date the above code is being passed back to the DB. I cannot create the database tables called date(3i) etc....

Comment: @user3216968 can you please include the error "as it is" in your logs in the question, and how you used the `date_select`

Comment: ok so first of all I have edited the above with how the code looks. I have two of these in the code.

Comment: change `f.date_select :date` to `f.date_select :field_name_in_the_db`

Comment: ok Doesn't make a difference if I change the name as the date is 3 fields so it always populates the (3i)(2i) etc at the end.

Comment: It would be very helpful if you shared your complete form